# Remembering how to find the elements of a certain order in a group

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I am working on a math problem and am stuck on remembering the correct way to solve it.

I basically need to figure out how much elements of order 8 are in Z (of 23432). (Where Z is a cyclic group under addition mod n).

I am not asking for the answer, I am looking for advice on how to remember how to find elements of an order for a group.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183839/7850) might get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\mid x^k\mid=\frac n{\operatorname{gcd}(n,k)}$, where $n=\mid x\mid$, in any cyclic group.

Perhaps try a smaller group first.  Say $\Bbb Z_9$.  How many elements of order $3$?  The equivalence class of $3$. Also $6$. So there are two such elements. Use the hint to see these are the only two.

How many elements of order $4$?  The answer is none. That's because $9$ and $4$ are *relatively prime*.

There is a theorem (Lagrange's theorem), that says the order of an element of a finite group has to divide the order of the group.

So, one of the first things to check is if $8\mid 23432$.  I think it does.  Thus, there's at least one.  Now use the hint to find it and any others.

This'll give you something to gnash your teeth on.  Good luck!

Ps.  As you will have seen in the linked answer above,  the answer winds up being $\varphi (n)$, where $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function (if there are any solutions).   Thus in the example I gave, $\varphi (3)=2$.  Similarly,  the answer to your question will be $\varphi (8)$.